# Will this function always have four lines of output?

Tags: c, fork

Will the following function always have four lines of output? If not, what is the reason? Like in which cases?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("hello1\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try running it and see.

Comment: Are you worried about ``fork()`` failing? If not, just read the documentation of ``fork()`` and you will easily find the answer.

Comment: They may not always be in the same order.

Comment: This question is really broad. In extreme corner case even simple `printf` may not work or program will crash because of insufficient resources. For example you set stack limit to 1kB or no new process can be created.

Comment: if `fork()` returns -1 there will be 3 lines .... but without `#include <stdio.h>` it can sing the lyrics of spanish hymn :)

Comment: Looks like it will always print 4 newlines somewhere in its output.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing to notice here is that [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) can very well fail, returning `-1`, and in that case `printf()` will be only called 3 times. Furthermore, [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) can fail too. So to answer your question:

> Will this function always have four lines of output?

No. You cannot say anything about it without running the program or making some assumptions first, and you definitely cannot say "always".

Answer (score 1):

On  success of `fork()`, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child.  On failure, -1 is returned in the parent no child will be created(from fork man page).

So `fork()` can fail too. 
So your program will print 4 line on success(as child will print "C1H2I3L4D\n" and parent will print "hello1\n","helloh\n","helloqq\n" line).

On failure it will print only  3 line "hello1\n" before the fork call and "helloh\n","helloqq\n" after the fork (from the parent process and Child will not be created).

if you still have doubt open terminal and type `man fork`. Look at the return value.